# How zip/unzip handles the symbolic links on unix systems?

Tags: c++, qt, zip, unzip, quazip

I'm using QuaZip for compressing files. There is a bug in the lib when you try to archive some folders that contain symlinks(aliases on mac), the file attributes are not preserved correctly in the archive. Is there a possibility to set the filetype attribute (file, directory, symlink, etc) through Qt or unix API?
I saw that in Qt all the flags are handled via `QFile::setPermissions()` method.
[Here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp.html) in `QFileSystemEngine::setPermissions()`(Qt source) Qt implementation handles also other flags than the ones from `QFile::Permissions`.

From Qt source:

```
if (success && data) {
    data->entryFlags &= ~QFileSystemMetaData::Permissions;
    data->entryFlags |= QFileSystemMetaData::MetaDataFlag(uint(permissions));
    data->knownFlagsMask |= QFileSystemMetaData::Permissions;
}
```

How this situation is handled in zip/unzip utilities?

Comment: zlib does not directly process the zip file format.

Comment: Changed to zip/unzip tools... I'm interested in how the symlinks are archived and restored...